# how to move ellipse using an Accelerometer in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to move a very basic ellipse or image using Accelerometer on a phone

below i have set up xamarin Essentials Acceleromter but ellipse isnt moving and Z-coordinates is missing. any one know what am i doing wrong?

view

```xml
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ballEllipse" Fill="Green" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

view-backend

```cs
public partial class AccelerometerPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public AccelerometerPage2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Accelerometer.IsMonitoring)
            return;

        // Register and Staart Accelermeter
        Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
        Accelerometer.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);
    }

    void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ballEllipse.TranslateTo(e.Reading.Acceleration.X, 
            e.Reading.Acceleration.Y, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it should work, because the value of `Acceleration.X`, `Acceleration.Y` is too small, the Ellipse doesn't look like it's moving, and you can try to expand the value to see that it's moving. In addition, you're not capturing the Z coordinate here, so you can try to print its value.

```
async void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Reading;
        Console.WriteLine($"Reading: X: {data.Acceleration.X}, Y: {data.Acceleration.Y}, Z: {data.Acceleration.Z}");
        await ballEllipse.TranslateTo(e.Reading.Acceleration.X*100,
            e.Reading.Acceleration.Y*100, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: aww that is cool! your right it was working but value for x and y were too small (between -1 to 1)... so by timing it by 100 made a big difference. thanks!